# How to find Standard deviation using arrays and a for loop?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the standard deviation of an array using a for loop.
I have some code that might work but it gives me errors.
I would appreciate some guidance and help! :-)

Here is the code:

```
double StandardDeviation() {
    double Dog,Variance,StandardDeviationFormula;

    for (int k = 0; k < TheArrayAssingment.length; k++) {

         Dog = Dog + (TheArrayAssingment[k] - Average()) 
                      * (TheArrayAssingment[k] - Average());

         Variance = Dog / (TheArrayAssingment.length - 1);
         StandardDeviationFormula = Math.sqrt(Variance);

    }
    return StandardDeviationFormula;
}
```

Comment: 1) is this code you've written or code you've borrowed from an online source? 2) If an online source, where did you get it? 3) Consider telling us what errors you're getting including the error text and which line is causing the errors.

Comment: I wrote it.  The errors are :variable Dog might not have been initialized
   Dog = Dog + (TheArrayAssingment[k] - Average()) * (TheArrayAssingment[k] - Average());

Comment: and  variable StandardDeviationFormula might not have been initialized
 return StandardDeviationFormula;

Comment: So the obvious solution is to initialize your variables before using them. Figure out a decent initial value to give them and give it to them.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob. :-/ How do I do that?

Comment: Then initialize Dog and Variance: Just put `= 0.0` in their declarations.

Comment: Assign them a decent initial variable when you declare them. Give it a try, you can't break the computer.

Comment: Your formulas don't appear right either. Where did you get this formula or code?

Comment: I checked and the formula works...

Comment: OK, then you've solved your problem and your code now works correctly?

Comment: Yup. It works perfectly.

Comment: You might want to compare your results with those obtained from an online standard deviation calculator. Even if your answers seem correct, your code is in fact still way off base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are obviously a beginner at programming in general as well as new to Java, here is some general advice:

1. Always following the coding standards / convention.  They are there to make you code more readable for other people.  Do it even in little throw-away examples, so that you get into the habit of doing it in the cases where it matters.
2. It is a "universal" convention in Java that method and variable names start with a lower-case letter.  You have started them all with an upper-case letter.  Change `StandardDeviation` to `standardDeviation`, `Variance` to `variance` and so on.
3. Choose variable and method names that *accurately* reflect the intended meaning.  For instance:

   - `Dog` is obviously meaningless.
   - `TheArrayAssingment` might be meaningful, but I can't figure it out.
   - `StandardDeviationFormula` is inaccurate.  It doesn't contain a formula.  It contains a value that is the result of applying a formula.

   It also helps if you spell method and variable names correctly ...

   (There are exceptions to this.  For instance, most seasoned programmers think it is perfectly acceptable to use conventional and abbreviated names for local variables when the meaning is self-evident.  For example, `ex` or `e` for an exception, `i` / `j` / `k` for a loop variable, `it` for an iterator object.  As you read more of other peoples' code, you will get to see / understand the "idioms".)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
package cruft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * StatisticsUtil has statistics utility methods
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 7/21/12 7:30 PM
 */
public class StatisticsUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String arg : args) {
            values.add(Double.valueOf(arg));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("mean   : %10.4f", getMean(values)));
        System.out.println(String.format("median : %10.4f", getMedian(values)));
        System.out.println(String.format("std dev: %10.4f", getStandardDeviation(values)));
    }

    public static double getMean(List<Double> values) {
        double mean = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.size() > 0)) {
            for (double value : values) {
                mean += value;
            }
            mean /= values.size();
        }
        return mean;
    }

    public static double getStandardDeviation(List<Double> values) {
        double deviation = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.size() > 1)) {
            double mean = getMean(values);
            for (double value : values) {
                double delta = value-mean;
                deviation += delta*delta;
            }
            deviation = Math.sqrt(deviation/values.size());
        }
        return deviation;
    }

    public static double getMedian(List<Double> values) {
        double median = 0.0;
        if (values != null) {
            int numValues = values.size();
            if (numValues > 0) {
                Collections.sort(values);
                if ((numValues%2) == 0) {
                    median = (values.get((numValues/2)-1)+values.get(numValues/2))/2.0;
                } else {
                    median = values.get(numValues/2);
                }
            }
        }
        return median;
    }

    public static double getMean(double [] values) {
        double mean = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 0)) {
            for (double value : values) {
                mean += value;
            }
            mean /= values.length;
        }
        return mean;
    }

    public static double getStandardDeviation(double [] values) {
        double deviation = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (values.length > 1)) {
            double mean = getMean(values);
            for (double value : values) {
                double delta = value-mean;
                deviation += delta*delta;
            }
            deviation = Math.sqrt(deviation/values.length);
        }
        return deviation;
    }

    public static double getMedian(double [] values) {
        double median = 0.0;
        if (values != null) {
            int numValues = values.length;
            if (numValues > 0) {
                Arrays.sort(values);
                if ((numValues%2) == 0) {
                    median = (values[(numValues/2)-1]+values[numValues/2])/2.0;
                } else {
                    median = values[numValues/2];
                }
            }
        }
        return median;
    }
}
```